# I'm trying to get the fore color of a textbox in vb.net and convert it into a string in order to save it as a txt file

Tags: vb.net

I am saving certain things from the textbox e.g. font size, font name, font style, contents of textbox. I am doing this in order to re open the file again and be able to format the text. (I am creating an app called 'Letter' - a sh*t copy of word.)

I have tried converting it into a string but that didn't work so I converted it into an integer and that didn't work either. I have googled my heart out trying to find someone that has had the same problem as me but, I could not find anything that would help.

This is the code that is giving me problems:

```
File.AppendAllText(Form1.address, AsciiSwitch(Form1.textEntry.Text, randomNumber) & "+" & Form1.textEntry.Font.Style & "+" & Form1.fSize & "+" & Form1.textEntry.Font.Name & "+" & randomNumber & "+" & Form1.textEntry.ForeColor)
```

Only the very last bit is causing my problems(incase you're wondering, textEntry is the text box in which the text is coming from and the "+"s are so that I can easily split the string and get the different values easily)

The error its spitting out:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Type of argument 'Number' is 'System.Drawing.Color', which is not numeric.
```

### Please, if you are answering, could you keep the answers simple as I have only started learning VB in school for 1 term and I can get quite overloaded with overly-complex answers

Edit: Setting_Reload:

```
Public Sub Setting_Reload()
        textEntry.Text = AsciiSwitch(Open.unformat(0), Open.unformat(4) - Open.unformat(4) * 2)
        fSize = Open.unformat(2)
        If fSize < 1 Then
            fSize = 1
        Else
            textEntry.Font = New Font(textEntry.Font.Name, fSize, textEntry.Font.Style, textEntry.Font.Unit)
        End If
        If Open.unformat(1) = 2 Then
            textEntry.Font = New Font(textEntry.Font.Name, textEntry.Font.Size, FontStyle.Italic, textEntry.Font.Unit)
        ElseIf Open.unformat(1) = 1 Then
            textEntry.Font = New Font(textEntry.Font.Name, textEntry.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold, textEntry.Font.Unit)
        ElseIf Open.unformat(1) = 4 Then
            textEntry.Font = New Font(textEntry.Font.Name, textEntry.Font.Size, FontStyle.Underline, textEntry.Font.Unit)
        ElseIf Open.unformat(1) = 0 Then
            textEntry.Font = New Font(textEntry.Font.Name, textEntry.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular, textEntry.Font.Unit)
        End If
        textEntry.Font = New Font(Open.unformat(3), textEntry.Font.Size, textEntry.Font.Style, textEntry.Font.Unit)
        textEntry.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(Open.unformat(4))
    End Sub
```

Excuse code if a bit special

Writing of file:

```
            Form1.address = addressBox.Text 'This is where the saving code actually go!
            If Not File.Exists(Form1.address) Then
                Form1.creator = File.Create(Form1.address)
                Form1.creator.Close()
            End If
            ' turn out i idiot and do not need this code(Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)) 'Pauses so that the same code is using the same file at the same time so that vb isn't like "No *Demonic Screeching* You are not allowed to do that!"
            Dim rn As New Random
            randomNumber = rn.Next(1, 50)
            File.AppendAllText(Form1.address, AsciiSwitch(Form1.textEntry.Text, randomNumber) & "+" & Form1.textEntry.Font.Style & "+" & Form1.fSize & "+" & Form1.textEntry.Font.Name & "+" & randomNumber & "+" & Form1.textEntry.ForeColor.ToArgb().ToString())
            Me.Close()
```

Reading of file:

```
            Form1.address = addressBox.Text 'This is where the saving code actually go!
            Form1.reader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Form1.address)
            unformat = Form1.reader.Split("+")
            Form1.Setting_Reload()
            Me.Close()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204638/discussion-on-question-by-eoin-im-trying-to-get-the-fore-color-of-a-textbox-in).

Comment: And the index of the color's value when you split the text should be 5 and not 4. So what's the value of `Open.unformat(5)`?